# $p(x)=(x^2-2\text{Re}(\lambda)x+|\lambda|^2)q(x)$ with $p\in P(\mathbb{R})$. Solve for $q$ why can't we immediately conclude its coeff are real?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation

Consider the following theorem from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* for factorizing a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$.

> Suppose $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is a nonconstant polynomial.
>
> Then $p$ has a unique factorization (except for the order of the
> factors) of the form
>
> $$p(x)=c(x-\lambda_1)\ldots
>  (x-\lambda_m)(x^2+b_1x+c_1)\ldots(x_2+b_Mx+c_M)$$
>
> where
> $c,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m,b_1,\ldots,b_M,c_1,\ldots,c_M\in\mathbb{R}$
> with $b_j^2<4c_j$ for each $j$.

**The proof of this theorem goes as follows**

We can think of $p$ as an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$.

If all the (complex) zeros of $p$ are real, then by we can factorize $p$ into

$$p(z)=c(z-\lambda_1)\ldots(z-\lambda_m)\tag{1}$$

where $c,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m\in\mathbb{R}$ .

In this case we are done.

If  $p$ has a zero $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\lambda\notin\mathbb{R}$ then we can still factorize $p$ into (1). However, we are looking for a factorization in which all the factors are real.

We know that $\bar{\lambda}\in\mathbb{C}$ is also a root of $p$ .

Thus,

$$p(x)=(x-\lambda)(x-\bar{\lambda})q(x)$$
$$=(x^2-x\bar{\lambda}-x\lambda+|\lambda|^2)q(x)$$
$$(x^2-2\text{Re}(\lambda)x+|\lambda|^2)q(x)\tag{2}$$

for some polynomial $q\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ with degree two less than the degree of $p$.

> If we can prove that $q$ has real coefficients, then by using
> induction on the degree of $p$, we can conclude that $(x-\lambda)$
> appears in the factorization of $p$ exactly as many times as
> $(x-\bar{\lambda})$.

To prove that $q$ has real coefficients, we solve (2) for $q(x)$

$$q(x)=\frac{p(x)}{x^2-2\text{Re}(\lambda)x+|\lambda|^2}\tag{3}$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

> The equation above implies that $q(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all
> $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**My question is about the step above.**

Since $p(x)\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ from the definition of polynomial in the book this means that $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

The denominator in (3) seems to also be a real number.

Since the coefficients of $p(x)$ are real, why can't we conclude already at this point that the coefficients of $q$ are real?

The rest of the proof in the book shows that the coefficients of $q$ are real in a different way.

> Writing
>
> $$q(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}$$
>
> where $n=\deg{p}$ and $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-2}\in\mathbb{C}$.

So again, here we see that the coefficients of $q$ are still possibly complex.

> Thus,
> $$0=\text{Im}(q(x))=\text{Im}(a_0)+\text{Im}(a_1)x+\ldots+\text{Im}(a_{n-2})x^{n-2}\tag{4}$$
>
> for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

(4) is a polynomial that is equal to zero for all $x$ and so the
coefficients must all be zero.
$$\text{Im}(a_0)=\ldots\text{Im}(a_{n-2})=0$$

Thus all the coefficients of $q$ are real as desired.